# How can I simplify this JavaScript and not duplicate the code for different variables/IDs?

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML**

```
<!-- This div is populated by the code in script.js -->
<div class="accordion" id="AccordionOne">
  <div id="App">
    <p>App</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**script.js** 
Is there a way to customise the following code so that instead of duplicating it (for FAQs international), it accommodates for both UK and International FAQs variables in content.js? Thank you in advance :)

```
document.getElementById("App").innerHTML = accordionItemsUk.map(function fullFAQList(accordionItemsUk) {
  return ['<div class="accordion-item"><h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading'
      + accordionItemsUk.itemNumber +
      '"><button class="accordion-icon collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse'
      + accordionItemsUk.itemNumber +
      '" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse'
      + accordionItemsUk.itemNumber +
      '">'
      + accordionItemsUk.title +
      '</button></h2><div id="collapse'
      + accordionItemsUk.itemNumber +
      '" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading'
      + accordionItemsUk.itemNumber +
      '"data-bs-parent="#AccordionOne"><div class="accordion-body">'
      + accordionItemsUk.content +
      '</div></div></div>'];
}).join('');
```

**content.js**

```
let accordionItemsUk = [
    {
        title: "FAQ1",
        content: "Content 1",
        itemNumber: "One"
    },
    {
        title: "FAQ2",
        content: "Content 2",
        itemNumber: "Two"
    }
];

let accordionItemsInternational = [
    {
        title: "FAQ1",
        content: "Content 1",
        itemNumber: "One"
    },
    {
        title: "FAQ2 Invite",
        content: "Content 2",
        itemNumber: "Two"
    }
];
```

Comment: Sure, just have a single `accordionItems` that you use, and assign the value of that `accordionItems` dynamically based on user selection (either the international one or the UK one, for example). Where you stash these i18n-specific javascript objects is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @rogue. That would work if we had to make a selection, either UK or International before displaying the Faqs, but we don't. Both UK an INT Faqs are displayed in the same page. I'm starting to believe that, yes only with a select region action we can do what we are trying to achieve... prove me wrong!? =)

Comment: Do you have two separate accordions? One for UK and one for INT?

Comment: @Timur yes each section (UK, INT) have several accordions each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break out the `map` function with the parameter being the list variable then then call this function to generate the content for each accordion. This way you don't duplicate the code that generates the accordion content. Assuming you have different ids for each accordion, you could do something like this:

```js
let accordionItemsUk = [
  {
    title: 'FAQ1',
    content: 'Content 1',
    itemNumber: 'One'
  },
  {
    title: 'FAQ2',
    content: 'Content 2',
    itemNumber: 'Two'
  }
]

let accordionItemsInternational = [
  {
    title: 'FAQ1',
    content: 'Content 1',
    itemNumber: 'One'
  },
  {
    title: 'FAQ2 Invite',
    content: 'Content 2',
    itemNumber: 'Two'
  }
]

function fullFAQList(list) {
  return list
    .map((item) => [
      '<div class="accordion-item"><h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading' +
        item.itemNumber +
        '"><button class="accordion-icon collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse' +
        item.itemNumber +
        '" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse' +
        item.itemNumber +
        '">' +
        item.title +
        '</button></h2><div id="collapse' +
        item.itemNumber +
        '" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading' +
        item.itemNumber +
        '"data-bs-parent="#AccordionOne"><div class="accordion-body">' +
        item.content +
        '</div></div></div>'
    ])
    .join('')
}

document.getElementById("AppUK").innerHTML = fullFAQList(accordionItemsUk)
document.getElementById("AppInternational").innerHTML = fullFAQList(accordionItemsInternational)
```

```html
UK:
<div id="AppUK"></div>
<hr>
International:
<div id="AppInternational"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution works like a charm @Tumir! The only update I needed to do in order for the accordions to work is making sure that each 'itemNumber' is unique in each array! Many thanks, really appreciate your time and help. Cheers